# Hyperledger Fabric SimulateProposal Error with high input send rate

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Hello I created a Hyperledger Fabric network that works fine when I submit a few transaction proposals at a time, but since I have to do some benchmark tests I'm having errors when I send several proposals to peers with high send rate. The network has these elements:

> - 3 Organizations
> - 3 Peers (one for each Org)
> - 1 Orderer
> - 1 Channel
> - 1 Java Chaincode compiled with fabric-chaincode-shim 1.4.4
> - The endorsement policy for the chaincode requires positive replies from all peers to valide transactions

All run on a single machine with:

> Intel i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
>
> 8 GB RAM DDR4
>
> Ubuntu 19.04 with kernel 5.0.0-35-generic
>
> Docker version 19.03.4
>
> docker-compose version 1.21.0

Docker containers for peers and orderer use Fabric images at version 1.4.3, but I tried latest and the outcome is the same.

I use Hyperledger Caliper to submite proposals at high send rate, some of them are accepted by peers (the number varies between execution) but others failed with this error:

> Transaction[901d0036b2] life-cycle errors:
>
> Proposal response error by peer0.org1.com: transaction returned with failure: Failed to submit task for processing

I report here the piece of the peer's log with the error:

```
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1439 21:14:56:720 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager onChaincodeMessage       [2b83c641] {
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 143a   "type": "TRANSACTION",
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 143b   "payload": "ChVpbml6aWFDb3JzYU1vYlN0YXRpY2EKCHBhc3F1YWxlCgp0cmVuaXRhbGlhCggxMTcwODM0MgoFMTM6MDAKBGF1dG8KFnBhcmNoZWdnaW9fZnVvcmlncm90dGEKA2duaQ==",
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 143c   "txid": "2b83c641371573b49d7d88589404c14ac5b03fd14a1a7e538cdfb14359972a25",
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 143d   "proposal": {
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 143e     "proposalBytes": "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",
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 143f     "signature": "MEUCIQDMAGTa6+CuBfav5v9+UsVo9vde5nMYIYbQpvDHgYrTRgIgeYseOCIm1CTwx3c8oIMVUkfVDt5nSvb6Ytd7x5lCtAk="
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1440   },
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1441   "channelId": "mychannel"
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1442 }
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1443 21:14:56:720 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager handleMsg                [2b83c641] Received TRANSACTION
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1444 21:14:56:720 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager newTask                  > newTask:created 2b83c641371573b49d7d88589404c14ac5b03fd14a1a7e538cdfb14359972a25
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1445 21:14:56:721 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager newTask                  > newTask:submitting 2b83c641371573b49d7d88589404c14ac5b03fd14a1a7e538cdfb14359972a25
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1446 21:14:56:721 WARNING org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager newTask                  Failed to submit task 2b83c641371573b49d7d88589404c14ac5b03fd14a1a7e538cdfb14359972a25Task java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun@39cf8f2a rejected from org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskExecutor@e00a3e59[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 15]
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1447 java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun@39cf8f2a rejected from org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskExecutor@e00a3e59[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 15]
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1448   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1449   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 144a   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 144b   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.asyncRunStage(CompletableFuture.java:1640)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 144c   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync(CompletableFuture.java:1858)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 144d   at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager.newTask(InnvocationTaskManager.java:226)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 144e   at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager.handleMsg(InnvocationTaskManager.java:172)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 144f   at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager.onChaincodeMessage(InnvocationTaskManager.java:141)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1450   at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeSupportClient$$Lambda$148.0000000094ECAD00.accept(Unknown Source)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1451   at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeSupportClient$1.onNext(ChaincodeSupportClient.java:86)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1452   at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeSupportClient$1.onNext(ChaincodeSupportClient.java:82)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1453   at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onMessage(ClientCalls.java:429)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1454   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1455   at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1456   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:599)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1457   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1458   at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1459   at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 145a [mychannel][2b83c641] Exit chaincode: name:"mycontract"  (93ms)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 145b   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 145c   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 145d   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:819)
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 145e 
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 145f 21:14:56:722 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeSupportClient$2 accept                 > sendToPeer 2b83c641371573b49d7d88589404c14ac5b03fd14a1a7e538cdfb14359972a25
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.com-mycontract-v0] func2 -> INFO 1460 21:14:56:722 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeSupportClient$2 accept                 < sendToPeer 2b83c641371573b49d7d88589404c14ac5b03fd14a1a7e538cdfb14359972a25
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.723 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 1461 [mychannel][2b83c641] failed to invoke chaincode name:"mycontract" , error: transaction returned with failure: Failed to submit task for processing
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.processChaincodeExecutionResult
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:266
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:240
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:147
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:146
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:247
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:500
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:32
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler.func1
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:169
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:31
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.(*Throttle).UnaryServerIntercptor
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm/throttle.go:54
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging/server.go:91
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics/interceptor.go:30
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:39
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:171
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:982
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1208
peer0.org1.com         | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:686
peer0.org1.com         | runtime.goexit
peer0.org1.com         |    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337
peer0.org1.com         | 2019-11-25 21:14:56.724 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 1462 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.1:34430 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=96.086094ms
```

As the message INFO 1447 suggests the peer fails to create a new task for the proposal, probably because many requests arrive together.
Is this consideration correct? Is there any way to change the maximum number of parallel tasks that a peer can create? Because this situation happens even with a rate of 100 rps and I think I can push performances further.

**SOLUTION**

As reported on this link:

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-17110

When Java chaincodes are compiled with fabric-chaincode-shim at version 1.4.4 the default thread pool is set too low, using the workaround described on the link I changed the pool queue size to decrease discarded transactions under high load conditions.

Thanks to david_k for the reply.

Comment: If you are using 1.4.4 of the java shim for your chaincode then you might be hitting this issue https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-17110

Comment: Are you using level db or couch db?

Comment: @david_k yes that was the problem and the suggested workaround solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Transaction throughput depends on various factor.
There are different Configurable parameters in hyperledger fabric

- Block Size
- Endorsement Policy
- Channel
- State Database

Play around with these paramentrs for better throughput(tps).

There are some major bottlenecks as well

- Crypto operations
- Serial Validation of tx in block
- Multiple rest API to couch DB

If we are sending tx more than the network capacity, the tx will get failed. CryptoOperation is most heavy, In case if you are using node SDK(API), just creating client object and channel object it takes almost 150 to 200 ms(varies with resources).
Try changing batch size and batch time in genesis block or maybe do some changes in endorsement policy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, surely I will consider these factors on my tests to improve avg latency and throughput. It seemed strange to me a high number of failed transactions even with few parallel requests, I would see the largest possible number of accepted transactions even if they have to wait increasing latency.  Starting from the bug reported by david_k now I know that I can change the thread pool queue size and that solved the problem, this is another factor I should consider for testing performance, maybe discard some transactions under high load conditions to decrease latency.